# GroupBox.Controls.count does not Update in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to Search through a series of contacts. (saved in an xml file, and then recovered to the variable myContacts) the code for searching is fine, it gets the right results, my problem is Showing the contact in the text boxes.
This is my code for showing the results in the text boxes:

```
private void showContact(int index)
    {
        txtNameResult.Text = myContacts[index].getName();
        txtFNameResult.Text = myContacts[index].getFName();
        txtNumberResult1.Text = myContacts[index].getSingleNumber(0);
        int position = 30;
        for (int i = 1; i < myContacts[index].getNumCount(); i++)
        {
            TextBox formtxtBox = txtNumberResult1;
            TextBox txtMyNum = new TextBox();
            gbResult.Controls.Add(txtMyNum);
            txtMyNum.Size = formtxtBox.Size;
            txtMyNum.Location = new Point(formtxtBox.Location.X, formtxtBox.Location.Y + position);
            position += 30;
            txtMyNum.Text = myContacts[index].getSingleNumber(i);
            txtMyNum.ReadOnly = true;
            txtMyNum.Name = "txtNumberResult" + (i + 1).ToString();
            txtMyNum.TabIndex = i + 2;
            if (this.Height < 414)
            {
                gbResult.Height += 30;
                this.Height += 30;
            }

        }//end of for
    }//end of show contact
```

and this is my form:

> ![search
>   Form][1]

each contact can have up to 5 numbers and with each extra number a text box is added under the txtNumberResult1 and the groupbox and form height are extended.
the problem is that when I search for a contact with 5 numbers it shows it correctly but if I search for another contact AFTER that, the extra textboxes don't delete.
this is rather odd, but after an hour of debugging I finally found out that the problem is in my `clearResults()` code the `gbResult.Controls.count` (**gbResult** is the groupbox) is 8 (it should be 11 now)
this is my `clearResults()` code(the code that executes at the beginning of Save button click event, it resets everything):

```
private void clearResults()
    {
        gbResult.Focus();
        txtNameResult.Text = "";
        txtFNameResult.Text = "";
        txtNumberResult1.Text = "";
        foreach (Control txtBox in gbResult.Controls)
        {
                if (txtBox.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    if (txtBox.Name != "txtNumberResult1" && txtBox.Name != "txtNameResult" && txtBox.Name != "txtFNameResult")
                    {
                        //remove the controls
                        txtBox.Text = "";
                        gbResult.Controls.Remove(txtBox);
                        txtBox.Dispose();
                    }//end of if
                }//end of if
        }//end of foreach
        //shrink the form
        while (this.Height > 294 && gbResult.Height > 129)
        {
            this.Height -= 30;
            gbResult.Height -= 30;
        }
    }//end of clear results
```

thank you in advance and sorry if it seems a bit confusing!
PS: I can't post images as I don't have the required rep :|

EDIT:
This is the correct clearResults() method:

```
private void clearResults()
    {
        gbResult.Focus();
        txtNameResult.Text = "";
        txtFNameResult.Text = "";
        txtNumberResult1.Text = "";
        //foreach (Control txtBox in gbResult.Controls)
        for (int i = 15; i > -1; i--)
        {

            try
            {
                var txtBox = gbResult.Controls[i];
                if (txtBox.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    if (txtBox.Name != "txtNumberResult1" && txtBox.Name != "txtNameResult" && txtBox.Name != "txtFNameResult")
                    {
                        //remove the controls
                        txtBox.Text = "";
                        gbResult.Controls.Remove(txtBox);
                        txtBox.Dispose();
                    }//end of if
                }//end of if
            }//end of try
            catch (Exception)
            {

                continue;
            }
        }//end of for

        //shrink the form
        while (this.Height > 294 && gbResult.Height > 129)
        {
            this.Height -= 30;
            gbResult.Height -= 30;
        }
    }//end of clear results
```

For those who have the same problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `clearResult()` method try removing the controls in reverse order:

```
for (int i = 20; i > -1; i--)
```

Comment: my God it Worked!! Thank you so much :D Not sure what was the problem though :S

Comment: When you delete in forward order you run the risk of deleting an item and all the items with indexes above the one you deleted shuffling down one. When you increment the counter in the loop and the shuffle happens you jump over items (leaving gaps in the sequence).